# laravel get data in view table if due date having 3 day

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

im tying to get data in view table if next payment date near 3days i need to get data in view table

**example**
next due date 15-4-2022
current date  11-4-2022 //Carbon::now

if date having near to 3days show data in table //name

if not then don't show any thing

```
Payment::select( 'next_due_date')->whereDate('next_due_date', Carbon::now)->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this one:

```
//if your payment date is 15-4-2022 then you have to add 4 days in carbon objects.
 $dueDate = Carbon::now()->addDays(4);
 Payment::select( 'next_due_date')->whereDate('next_due_date', $dueDate)->get();

//or

 Payment::select( 'next_due_date')->whereDate('next_due_date', date('Y-m-d', strtotime("4 days")))->get();
```

Comment: thank you  it works is there possible to once it display data before 4 days it shoed show permanently in view table

Comment: @Malkhazi Dartsmelidze is there possible to once it display data before 4 days it shoed show permanently in view table